# FCM Message not Received on iOS App when sent to a topic

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications with FCM to an iOS App. It works fine when I send it to the token, but it doesn't work when I send it to a topic. I tried subscribing the App to the topics using this:

```
string[] topics = { "all", "test" };
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe(topics);
```

(This is using the *Plugin.FirebasePushNotification*) or using this:

```
string[] tokens = { e.Token };
FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SubscribeToTopicAsync(tokens, "test");
FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SubscribeToTopicAsync(tokens, "all");
```

(This is using *FirebaseAdmin*) It's both in the App.xaml.cs, the first one beeing under InitializeComponent(); and the second one beeing in OnTokenRefresh. It works fine on android, but not on iOS. Keep in mind, that e.Token is the Token. I even tried to subscribe in the AppDelegate.cs, but it didn't work there either. I think it could be because it tries to subscribe before I even said "Yes" on the device so it can send me Notifications. I'm using an iPhone SE with iOS 15.3.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In the *AppDelegate.cs* you can override the *RegisteredForRemoteNotifications* and you can just subscribe there. This means, it will subscribe if the user grants the permission to send remote notifications. After that it worked perfectly.